# QComboBox.curfrentText() not working - i always get TypeError: execute() argument 1 must be str, not tuple

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

What's wrong with my sqlstr

```
def clicker(self):
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        sqlstr = ('''
                  SELECT t1.column3, t2.column2, t2.column3, t2.column4
                  FROM t1
                  INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.id_number = t2.id_number
                  WHERE t1.column3 = ? AND t2.column2 = ?''',
                  (self.qcombobox1.currentText()), (self.qcombobox2.currentText()))
```

I am getting TypeError: execute() argument 1 must be str, not tuple

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you might want to add the *sql* tag so your question will been seen by sql specialists giving you more chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give `execute()` `sqlstr` as an argument, try `execute(*sqlstr)` instead to unpack the tuple as different arguments.

Comment: @ArielSerrano I'm glad I could help. If my solution has solved your problem, please be free to click the checkmark next to it and [accept it as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). This lets other users know that your question was solved and awards us both a reputation bonus.